# How can I improve performance of my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a list of items. Items have several actions assigned to them. (see screenshot).

One may choose to directly click on an icon next to each row or check a checkbox on the left hand side.

The issue is that after clicking an item OR checking a checkbox of several items and then clicking an action there is a lag (a second or so). Imagine having 100 rows or more.

[image]

How can I improve the performance of my javascript code?

sample HTML of one row:

```
<tr id="1960AGIMMGMRTB20314" class="">
                        <td class="checkbox">
                                     <input type="checkbox" value="1960" class="checkbox">     

                        </td>
                        <td class="">
                            <p><a href="/Devices/View/1960">GD009000246</a></p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="platform">PCGames</td>
                        <td class="cat">Up</td>
                        <td class="platform">
                            <div class="pbar"><span class="progresslabel"></span></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="date">10.48.1.236</td>   
                        <td class="options clearfix">
                                    <a title="" class="iconMagnifier tip" href="/Packages/View/AGI-MM-GM-RTB-2.0.3.1.4">View</a>
<a title="" href="/Packages/PackageActionAsyncDeletePackage" data-ajax-type="DeletePackage" data-ajax-packageid="AGI-MM-GM-RTB-2.0.3.1.4" data-ajax-machineid="1960" class="iconDelete action tip">Remove</a>                            
                        </td>       
                    </tr>
```

javascript:

```
     // action invoker
    $("a.action:not(.remove)").click(function (e) { // .remove => do not execute on download tasks page
        var obj = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('disablelink')) {
            var machineIds = getSelection(obj);
            if (machineIds.length > 0) {
                packageAction(obj.attr("data-ajax-packageid"), machineIds, obj.attr("data-ajax-type"));
            };
        }
        $(".checkall").attr("checked", false);
    });

function getSelection(obj) {
    var selected = new Array();
    if (obj.attr('data-ajax-machineId')) {
        selected.push(obj.attr('data-ajax-machineId'));
    } else {
        $("input.checkbox:checkbox:checked:not(.checkall)").each(function () {
            var machineId = $(this).val();
            var packageId = obj.attr("data-ajax-packageid");
            var operation = obj.attr("data-ajax-type");
            if ($("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "").size() != 0) {
                var row = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "");
                row.has("a[data-ajax-type=" + operation + "]:not(.hide)").length ? selected.push(machineId) : $(this).attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    }
    return selected;
}  

    // download, install, uninstall, remove, activate, deactivate package
    function packageAction(packageId, machineIds, operationType) {
.....// to implement - not needed
```

Comment: Who is voting this up?!?

Comment: without a demo that replicates problem doubt you will get much help. Lag could be ajax related. Binding checkbox actons to a data object would cut down a lot of DOM searching which might help

Comment: Here's some changes that caught my eye ( mostly about the data-attributes ): http://pastebin.com/CG7tUuGS Also, I'm just gonna say, you have some crazy selectors in there, E.g. `"input.checkbox:checkbox:checked:not(.checkall)"` and you might want to post the code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Joonas(+1) has a point all this selectors "crazy" and repetitiv "attr" get/set, could cause performace issues(also the browser dom-tree-redraws), for a  few rows it would could be okay, but here we are be talking of about 1400+ html elements, if the html-code show is only one row and you are displaying 100 or more....

Comment: thanks Joonas. I learned something new from your code :). that works. also I improved selecting objects with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222914/javascript-check-if-dom-element-exists-best-practice

Comment: @Joonas you should probably post an answer

Comment: I believe .each is supposed to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying objects out of the DOM is slow.  The best thing to do is hold all of your data in javascript objects, do all the calculations and stuff you want, THEN update the DOM all at once.  Ember.js and some other javascript libraries/tools have bound data which is cool, meaning you change an attribute in the javascript object and it automatically updates the DOM!