# javascript check if DOM element exists best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best practice to check if a DOM element exists in javascript?

Should one check if an item exists prior to using it, like so?

```
if ($("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "").size() != 0) {
  var row = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "");
}
```

wouldn't this execute `packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase()` twice?

OR would this be better option?

```
var row = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + ""); 
if (row)
{
  // do something
}
```

However, wouldn't it throw an exception when not found?

Comment: remove this from both lines `+ ""`.

Comment: `size()` is deprecated....use `length` instead

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you're actually working with DOM elements, then yes, you should check that it exists before you attempt to work with it to avoid JavaScript errors. However, you're **not** working with DOM elements, you're working with a jQuery object that (potentially) contains DOM elements.

jQuery functions already handle cases where there are no matches in its set of elements, so you don't need to explicitly check for yourself that there are elements before attempting to work with them. You'd only need to do so if you're trying to directly reference DOM elements from inside that set, using the `.get()` function or the `[index]` square bracket notation.

As an aside, the [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) jQuery function was deprecated in version 1.8, you should use the jQuery object's `length` property directly to check if there are elements, so:

```
var $object = $('a-selector');
if($object.length) {
    // there's at least one matching element
}
```

Comment: That's not correct.  It should be `if ($object.length > 0)` - even for unfound selectors it still returns 0

Comment: @Archer What do you mean by "unfound selectors"? If you mean selectors that don't match any elements, then yes, it will return `0` which is exactly what we want. `0` is falsey, so the `if` condition will fail if there aren't any elements in the jQuery object.

Comment: Well I never!  Thanks Anthony - I never knew that 0 is read as false in an if statement.  That's why I was "correcting" you.  Thanks for my new thing learnt for the day.  Have a +1 :)

Comment: thanks all for your input but the explanation helped. thank you1

Comment: although Anthony is right, I consider that bad practice ... it is a form of implicit detection, which has potential pitfalls in principal ... in other words, using ( $object.length > 0 ) is a directly-on-point question to ask.

Comment: Yes, it is alot better to use > 0 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

General programming conventions say *don't repeat yourself*. So, in this case, you could at least do the finding of the thing only once and keep a variable reference:

```
var thing = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "");
```

Then the selection lookup doesn't happen twice, redundant method calls removed etc. This also has the benefit of allowing you to write more self-explanatory code, when you can name a variable to something meaningful, other than `thing`, or, *eeek!*, `a` (though it isn't necessarily so that code must be more meaningful, people *still* use names like `a`!)

```
if (thing != null) { }
if (thing.size() != 0) {

} 
etc.
```

As for calling methods multiple times, that's often unavoidable.

Comment: It's considered bad practice to specifically check for null in JS. Just check if thing exists, because it could also be undefined, 0 or false

Comment: @Anzeo Check for `null` or `undefined` as you wish, that wasn't my point.

Answer (score 1):

Better to cache it:

```
var machId = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase());
if (machId.size() != 0) {
   var row = machId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does, what you need is:

```
var a = $("#" + machineId + packageId.removeSpecialChars().toUpperCase() + "");
if (a.size()) {
    var row = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to see if the DOM element is exist in your HTML, but beer in mind that jQuery doesn't throw a fatal error if the element not exist in your DOM, but would a good practice to check, it adds one more secure layer on your code, there was something called .size() that deprecated from version 1.8, so not recommended to use even you use old version of jQuery, so the best solution at the moment would be something like below code:

```
if($('.class').length) { // check if any element with this class exist, if not exist, it return 0 and can not pass the if estatement
    // do something
}
```